# Disabling or hiding controls design guideline?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have checked the design guidelines from the Android developers recently and found the recommendation to use at least 4 states for interactive ui elements.

default, disabled, focused, pressed

see http://www.slideshare.net/AndroidDev/android-ui-design-tips, slide 13

On the other hand in slide 10 it is said to make the right things visible.

Now I am trying to figure out when to disable controls and when to hide them. I tend to think that if a control is not applicable at the moment, it should not be visible to reduce ui clutter.

On the other hand it kind of makes sense to me, to disable the zoom button when no more zooming is possible. Only kind of though. Maybe hiding would work even better.

I am not sure. Has anybody found any other references that might help on when to hide and when to mere disable a control. What factors do you need to take into account when you decide for one or the other?

Is there any Android or mobile application specific recommendation due to screen size or whatever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer to the link above pretty much sums it up. I would like to point out that it was a general scenario question. In specific environments, especially small-screened mobile devices, I think hiding becomes more important. I constantly try to find ways to hide things I don't use so that I can more quickly find the things I do want.

It might be best to hide elements that would be disabled for long periods of time and simply disable things that may be frequently enabled/disabled.

As for zooming, I find it frustrating when controls like that disappear. That is frequently used so I think it is inappropriate to hide it.

"What factors do you need to take into account when you decide for one or the other?"
I'd say user environment, how frequently it might be used/toggled, how important it is to the application or the user, and how closely it relates to other options/elements.

Answer (score 3):

The vague litmus test that we apply in our UI decisions for hiding versus disabling an action is as follows:

- does the user *ever* get to invoke that action based on their privilege/role/visibility level? if not, then hide the button; e.g.:

  - user has a guest role that has no admin privileges, so does not see an edit button
  - the account is in gold status, so does not see an extended feature button that platinum accounts see
- is the user prevented from invoking the action based on the target item's current *mode* that may change eventually? then disable the button but keep it shown; e.g.:

  - document is in draft mode, so the production push button is disabled
  - a download is still in progress, so the "open in finder" button is disabled
  - the current account resource limit prevents adding new resources to the account, so the add button is disabled (but an obvious plan upgrade or freeing up of resources will enable it)
- if action depends on item *type* (i.e. not likely to change), then hide it; e.g.:

  - hide option to download file as PDF for MP3 files
  - hide option to set up email signing certificate for users of type "guest"

Essentially, like mentioned above, this comes down to whether the user should expect to invoke the action within medium-term usage of the UI. If they never get to do it, then don't bother showing the action. If it is a temporary restriction based on item/system state, then show it as disabled, hopefully explaining why it is disabled.